# How to explain the difference of meaning between JToken and JsonToken in Newtonsoft.Json(Json.Net)

Tags: json.net

As mentioned,Please tell me the essence of JToken and JsonToken in Json.Net.

I can not distinguish the meaning about them clearly.

I am anxious for your answer! many thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is the abstract base class of `JObject`, `JArray`, `JProperty`, and `JValue`, which represent pieces of JSON data after they have been parsed.

[`JsonToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) is an enum that is used by `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` to indicate which type of token is being read or written.

You can find more information in the Json.Net [API reference](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/Introduction.htm).

Comment: Add to your answer that a JProperty is a JToken paired with a name (string) and this is perfect.